# I need help cleaning my /boot

Tags: boot, removing

I'm a linux nubie. For some reason my /boot is really small. I need to do a software update but when I try it says I need to free space. here is what is on my /boot now. I'm not sure what I should remove. I took a screen shot of what is on my /boot, any help in what is extra and what I should remove is appreciated. thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I free up more space in /boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89710/how-do-i-free-up-more-space-in-boot) and [How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)

Answer (score 0):

A safe way to remove the old kernels is to install [Ubuntu Tweak](http://ubuntu-tweak.com/).  Then click on "Start Janitor", check the "Old Kernel" box on the left, check the "Old Kernels" entry that appears in the middle, then click "Clean" and input your password.  You're done.

Answer (score 0):

To remove kernel version `3.19.0-xx-generic`, just do

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge linux-image-3.19.0-xx-generic
```

In case you also have the kernel headers installed, likewise remove `linux-headers-3.19.0-xx`.